# PHP - Break in variable

Tags: php, sendmail, var

Simple question, how do I put a break between variables in PHP and insert another variable between it? For example I want to send an email with an activation URL, which is defined earlier as $acticode. How do I insert it into the following (the way I've attempted it below doesn't work).

```
$message = "Your activation code is" , $acticode , "and you can activate it at blah blah";
```

Whole Snippet:

```
$acticode = "12345";
    $subject = "Please activate your account";
       $message = "Your activation code is" , $acticode , "and you can activate it at blah blah";
       $header = "From:test@test.com \r\n";
       $retval = mail ($email,$subject,$message,$header);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concatenation operator is `.` (period).

You need

```
$message = "Your activation code is" . $acticode . "and you can activate it at blah blah";
```

Comment: @TheDoonker You can also just put your variable inside the actual string, as long as your string is contained in double quotes (").